# How to Decrypt Video File chuck by chunk and pass to video view?

Tags: java, android, encryption

Here is my code to decrypt the whole video file and pass decrypted video file path to video view so how to decrypt video chunk by chunk and pass it to video view and after first chunk pass after that second chunk will be decrypted in background and after that second chunk decrypted pass it to video view how can achieve that

```
try
{

    FileInputStream encfis = new FileInputStream(Encrypted_File_Path);
    FileOutputStream decfos = new FileOutputStream(Decrypted_File_Path);

    Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    String encode ="8888888888888888";
    byte[] decodedKey = encode.getBytes();
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");

    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(decfos,decipher);

    int c;
    byte[] d1 = new byte[4096 * 2048];
    while((c = encfis.read(d1)) != -1)
    {
        cos.write(d1, 0, c);
        cos.flush();
    }
    cos.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: you need it for `MediaPlayer`? if so, what minimum API level is required?

Comment: minimum Api 14 so how can achieve from media player ?

Comment: `setDataSource(MediaDataSource dataSource)` but sorry you need 23, not 14, if you want 14 then use https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/